# how to make a custom horizontal alignment in mlreportgen.dom.*?

Tags: matlab, dom, pdf-generation, reportgenerator

How to make custom text and image alignment in

```
mlreportgen.dom.*
```

I used

```
HAlign()
```

but it is only having `'center','left','right'` is there any method to customize this? any solution will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this same question in Matworks community also and i got the answer as till now `mlreportgen.dom.*` only support `left,right and centre`.

coustomization is not supported till now.